# Including SQL Server Express with Application

Tags: installation, sql-server-express, nsis, redistributable

I'm bundling an application for distribution and SQL Server is a prequisite so we're including SQL Server Express. What's the easiest way to include SQL server in a point and click installer? In the past I've used NSIS, but it was always flaky when installing the .NET Framework, so .NET, SQL Server and our app seems like an impossible task.

It needs to be free, which probably cuts back my options a tad. Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Good tags help. Browse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIX? I would use WIX and the bootstrapper would install SQL Server Express.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a decent method. Thanks.

Comment: Decent enough - interesting enough - to be used by prety much all MS tools, though they use the custom UI approach (TONS of work).